# Can't resolve anchor tag

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to figure out, why here in React, an anchor tag is not working here in my code below. I use Bootstrap for styling. Here is my code below. The warning shows: "Can't resolve anchor"
Thank you for your assistance. Maybe should I delete div tag with IDs or rename it somehow.

```
return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="container-fluid align-items-center">
                <h1 className="display-1 font-weight-bold">{headerTitle}</h1>
                <h4 className="display-5">{subTitle}</h4>
                <p>{headerText}</p>
                {/*Social Icons*/}
                <div className="container mt-5">
                    <div className="row justify-content-center">
                        <div className="col-2">
                            <i className="fab fa-twitter"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-2">
                            <i className="fab fa-google-plus-g"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-2">
                            <i className="fab fa-reddit"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-2">
                            <i className="fab fa-whatsapp"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-2">
                            <i className="fab fa-facebook-messenger"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {/*Nav Link*/}
            <div className="container">
                <ul className="nav nav-tabs">
                    {/*About Place Link*/}
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <a href="#aboutPlace" className="nav-link active" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">About Place</a>
                    </li>
                    {/*Reviews Link*/}
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <a href="#reviews" className="nav-link" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Reviews</a>
                    </li>
                    {/*Map*/}
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <a href="#map" className="nav-link" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Map</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                {/*Tab Pane*/}
                <div className="tab-content mb-5">
                    {/*About Place Tab*/}
                    <div id="aboutPlace" className="tab-pane in active text-center mt-5" role="tabpanel">
                        <h2 className="mb-3">{title}</h2>
                        <p>{description}</p>
                        <img src={img} alt={title} className="img-thumbnail img-fluid"/>
                    </div>
                    {/*Reviews*/}
                    <div className="tab-pane" id="reviews" role="tabpanel">
                        Reviews Content
                    </div>
                    {/*Map*/}
                    <div className="tab-pane" id="map" role="tabpanel">
                        <iframe src={maps} title="Map"
                                style={{border: '0', height: '28.125rem', width: '100%', frameborder: '0'}}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue, just read again bootstrap documentation!:)

```
 return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="container-fluid align-items-center">
                <h1 className="display-1 font-weight-bold">{headerTitle}</h1>
                <h4 className="display-5">{subTitle}</h4>
                <p>{headerText}</p>
                {/*Social Icons*/}
                <div className="container mt-5">
                    <div className="row justify-content-center">
                        <div className="col-2">
                            <i className="fab fa-twitter"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-2">
                            <i className="fab fa-google-plus-g"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-2">
                            <i className="fab fa-reddit"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-2">
                            <i className="fab fa-whatsapp"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-2">
                            <i className="fab fa-facebook-messenger"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {/*Nav Link*/}
            <div className="container">
                <ul className="nav nav-tabs " role="tablist">
                    {/*About Place Link*/}
                    <li className="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a href="#aboutPlace" id="aboutPlace-tab" className="nav-link active" role="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" aria-controls="aboutPlace" aria-selected="true">About Place</a>
                    </li>
                    {/*Reviews Link*/}
                    <li className="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a href="#reviews" id="reviews-tab" className="nav-link" role="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" aria-controls="reviews" aria-selected="false">Reviews</a>
                    </li>
                    {/*Map*/}
                    <li className="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a href="#map" id="map-tab" className="nav-link" role="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" aria-controls="map" aria-selected="false">Map</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                {/*Tab Pane*/}
                <div className="tab-content mb-5" id="myTabContent">
                    {/*About Place Tab*/}
                    <div id="aboutPlace" className="tab-pane fade show active text-center mt-5" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="aboutPlace-tab">
                        <h2 className="mb-3">{title}</h2>
                        <p>{description}</p>
                        <img src={img} alt={title} className="img-thumbnail img-fluid"/>
                    </div>
                    {/*Reviews*/}
                    <div id="reviews" className="tab-pane fade mt-5" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="reviews-tab">
                        Reviews Content
                    </div>
                    {/*Map*/}
                    <div className="tab-pane fade" id="map" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="map-tab">
                        <iframe src={maps} title="Map"
                                style={{border: '0', height: '28.125rem', width: '100%', frameborder: '0'}}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default Details;
```